# Problema com OAuth2 JWT em WebApi2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Basicamente todo código está funcionando, eu consigo gerar meu token, eu consigo fazer tudo, porém não estou conseguindo validar o token.

Meu código está assim quando eu vou chamar a api. O que acontece é: Eu estou mandando o request com o token, mas mesmo assim não valida, o token está no header mas ele não consegue validar.

(Eu já adicionei as claims, parte de startup e startup.auth está configurada igual o do site, caso seja necessário posto o resto do código.)

```
[Authorize(Roles ="user")]
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/testeToken")]
public HttpResponseMessage testeToken()
{
    var user = User.Identity;
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent("{\"message\":\"asdasd\", \"payload\":\"\",\"response\":\"2123\"}")
    };

    return responseMessage;
}
```

Eu estou usando esse [tutorial](http://www.developerhandbook.com/c-sharp/create-restful-api-authentication-using-web-api-jwt/)

FilterConfig.cs :

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ValidateUserRoles());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}

public class ValidateUserRoles : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
           //
        }

    }
}
```

CustomOAuthProvider.cs :

```
public class CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            //context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            IdentityUser novo = new IdentityUser(context.UserName);

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(SetClaimsIdentity(context, novo), new AuthenticationProperties());
            context.Validated(ticket);

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        private static ClaimsIdentity SetClaimsIdentity(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context, IdentityUser user)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("user", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"user"));

            return identity;
        }
    }
```

CustomJwtFormat.cs :

```
public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
    {
        private static readonly byte[] _secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"]);
        private readonly string _issuer;

        public CustomJwtFormat(string issuer)
        {
            _issuer = issuer;
        }

        public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
            }

            var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(_secret);
            var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
            var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, null, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey));
        }

        public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs :

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Startup.Auth.cs :

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["issuer"];
        var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"]);


        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new[] { "Any" },
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
{
    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
}
        });


        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(issuer)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Quando você tenta acessar este endpoint ele dá erro de autorização?

Comment: `{
  "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}`

Request header:

Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFkbSIsInVzZXIiOiJhZG0iLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0LyIsImV4cCI6MTQ4MTkwMTEyOSwibmJmIjoxNDgxODk5MzI5fQ.ddh33ynUqZyKvth586abvw-ZVePxQ60mYZHZxDRVEtU

Comment: Não precisava postar o payload inteiro, era só confirmar *=)* Você tem que postar o código que trabalha com o token (gera/recebe/envia) e não o código do *controller*, deste só precisamos a assinatura e os *attributes*. A autenticação já funciona em outros lugares? Está usando WebAPI 2?

Comment: O código que trabalha com o token é igual ao que está no tutorial, não a autenticação não está funcionando. Eu achei que poderia ser problema com o método OnAuthorization, tentei fazer um filtro novo para a autorização, mas ele não entra nem no método.
`public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        { filters.Add(new ValidateUserRoles());}
    }

    public class ValidateUserRoles : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {}}}`

Comment: desculpe a péssima indentação

Comment: Você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar essas informações nela. Os comentários não servem bem pra isso

Comment: Sim, estou usando webAPI 2, tenho certeza que estou pecando em algo simples e não estou percebendo :(

Não entendo muito bem sobre tokens

Comment: Por isso que é necessário teu código pra gente entender o que você está fazendo... Não temos como te ajudar sem saber o que tá acontecendo.

Comment: Adicionei o código =)

Comment: Consegui resolver meu problema, assim que terminar meu código vou postar aqui =D

Comment: Guilherme a pergunta ainda está em aberto. Já resolveu? Caso positivo adicione a resposta.